# what is comma trailing in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const army = {
     name: 'karan',
     memb : [
            {
                captain: 'suraj',
            },
            {
                rifleMan: 'sanjay'
            },
            {
                grenadier: 'yogesh'
            }
      ]
}
    
const { name , memb:[, cap]} = army
    
console.log("cap ", cap)
```

This gives `cap  { rifleMan: 'sanjay' }`.

Can anyone please explain this concept and what it is called

Comment: What's `cap` in your code? What's the value of `memb:[, cap]`?

Comment: [Destructuring assignment - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) -> [Ignoring some returned values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#ignoring_some_returned_values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are de-structuring the `army` object. So `"karen"` is stored in `name` and from the `army.memb` which is an array you want the second element and store it in `cap`.

For example if you put two commas it means you want the third element of the `memb` array:

```js
const army = {
  name: 'karan',
  memb: [{
      captain: 'suraj',
    },
    {
      rifleMan: 'sanjay'
    },
    {
      grenadier: 'yogesh'
    }
  ]
}

const { name, memb: [,, cap]} = army


console.log("cap ", cap)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is feature of array `destructuring` in javascript. It is used to ignore or skip certain values while destructuring.

```
const [a, , b] = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a,b);   // 1,3
const [, a, b] = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a,b);   // 2,3
```